# Strange Data Appearing in WPF Appication (VS 2010)

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

I have a very odd situation

I am trying to help a junior colleague resolve an issue in a project. When we run the project in Visual Studio 2010 we are finding that a couple of text boxes are having their text property set to a value that doesnt exist in the solution at all, but is related to the project.

i.e. the textbox includes the text 'Test Risk Data', but that phrase exists nowhere in our solution. Also, I can confirm that the value is not being set anywhere in code (or config or settings etc), or calculated any way at all.

This is extremely strange - after 12 years .NET development experience I have never been this 'stumped' by an issue.

Any clues whatsoever will be most welcome.

**EDIT**

This only happens in debug mode ??????

Comment: If you can confirm that the value is not being set anywhere in code (or config or settings etc), or calculated any way at all, then I guess the only two options are: 1) you're both hallucinating, 2) the Universe doesn't work. Probably the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IVE FOUND THE ANSWER, AND YOU WONT BELIEVE IT - A REAL GOTCHA !!**

I got a clue when I disabled breakpoints. Then I realise that 1 breakpoint had the following hidden condition (I didnt see the little white dot in the red breakpoint icon circle)

`RiskTxtBox.Text = "Test Risk Data"` , which SHOULD have been `RiskTxtBox.Text` **==** `"Test Risk Data"`

Bloody junior developers !!

Oh well, solved now, thanks for everyones help

Comment: This goes against your comments; the text does not exist in the solution...?

Comment: I did a solution-wide text search, and didnt find it - sorry if I didnt make that clear